# Ipad bug: automatic switching of keyboard mode

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard

I am not able solve a strange bug in my iPad game, "Sometimes keyboard switches automatically
from alphabet characters to numeric characters while entering numbers on it".
Also please note that I am only allowing  numeric input by using - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string. I have not done anything else to switch keyboard mode.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "keyboardType" property of the UITextField.

```
myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

Comment: Thanks, this also fixed automatic switching problem.